# Criteria of irreducibility for polynomials with integer coefficients

Tags: reference-request

I would like to know where can I find some material related to this subject:

> Criteria of irreducibility for polynomials with integer coefficients.

I've searched in my number theory book from Niven and I didn't find anything about this.

Thanks

Comment: See this Wiki article and References: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion

Comment: @user35603 where can I find another criteria?

Comment: There are more here http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/some-polynomial-irreducibility-criteria/ and references are provided.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935/methods-to-see-if-a-polynomial-is-irreducible