# Help to understand this polynomial trick

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to understand this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/31272) which I copy here (I didn't ask to the user because he left MSE).

[image]

Could someone verify if my answer is correct and help me to understand the highlighted statement, maybe giving me a concrete example?

**My attempt:**

$\Leftarrow$

If $f$ is reducible, then $f(x)=h_1(x)h_2(x)=g(x+c)$, then $g(x)=h_1(x-c)h_2(x-c)$, so $g(x)$ is reducible.

$\Rightarrow$

If $g(x)$ is reducible, then $g(x)=h_1(x)h_2(x)=f(x-c)$, then $f(x)=h_1(x+c)h_2(x+c)$, so $f(x)$ is reducible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your understanding is correct. As an example, consider the polynomial
$$X^4+6X^3+14X^2+20X+21.$$
It is irreducible, which is easier to see after translating over $-1$.

Comment: Your proof is correct and "translating" the polynomial opens up applying criteria like Eisenstein's or reducing mod a prime.

Comment: @Servaes As an example I meant by this statement: "reduce g modulo a prime and/or apply Eisenstein to show that g is irreducible", can you give me an example what he means? thank you

Comment: @NickyHekster What do you mean by " reducing mod a prime"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the idea.  Basically we are exploiting the fact that the shift map, being  an *automorphism*, faithfully preserves multiplicative structure. Note that you also have to argue that the images of the factors remain nonzero nonunits for the proof to be complete.

Comment: I didn't understand what the uses means by "reduce g modulo a prime and/or apply Eisenstein to show that g is irreducible", can you give me an example what he means? thank you

Comment: @user75086 Similar to your proof, if $\,f\,$ is reducible then it will remain reducible mod $p$ as long as the degrees don't drop, i.e. $\,p\,$ doesn't divide the leading coefficient. Then, contrapositively, irreducible mod $p$ $\,\Rightarrow\,$ irreducible. Ditto for any multiplicative map that doesn't map a nonunit to a unit.

Comment: That's the main trouble in my question, what it means a polynomial be irreducible mod $p$?

Comment: @user75086 It means that it is an irreducible element when mapped into $\,\Bbb F_p[x],\,$ i.e. a nonunit $\ne 0$ with only trivial factorizations, i.e. $\,f = gh\,\Rightarrow\, g\mid 1\,$ or $\,h\mid 1,\,$  or, equivalently, $\,f\mid h\,$ or $\,f\mid g\,\,$ i.e. the only factors of $\,f\,$ are units or associates of $\,f.\ \ $

Comment: I hope not asking too much, but can you give a concrete example of what you have just said?

Comment: @user75086 $\ {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ f(x) = x^3-x+1\, $ is the constant function $1\,$ so has no roots mod $3,\,$ so is irreducible mod $3,\,$ so is irreducible over $\,\Bbb Q.\ \ $

Comment: Do you know some books which I can find more this stuff?

Comment: @user75086 Quotient (residue) rings are discussed in every abstract algebra textbook. These facts about irreducibility often occur as exercises.