# Is the polynomial $x^4+10x^2+1$ reducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial  $x^4+10x^2+1$  reducible over  $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Comment: Please search before asking a new question. This has been asked several times before: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665435/x4-10x2-1-is-irreducible-over-mathbb-q), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204279/show-that-x4-10x21-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that our polynomial has no integer roots and has no real roots. So if it is reducible, there are integers $a$ and $b$ for which
$$x^4+10x^2+1=(x^2+ax+1)(x^2+bx+1).$$ 
Can you end it now?

Comment: Why are the free terms of the factors positive?

Comment: @N. S $a$ or $b$ can be negative.

Comment: @N. S If one of them is negative so the second is negative and we can multiply by $-1$ and to get, which I wrote.

Comment: Your last example is impossible because our polynomial has no real roots.

Comment: I say again: Our polynomial has no real roots. You last example is not valid. See please better my post.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have any rational roots, by the rational roots test.

To see whether $f(x) = x^4+10x^2 + 1 = (x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ or not, try to solve the system of equations $a+c = 0$, $ac+b+d = 0$, $bd = 1$ over the integers.

Alternately, you could find the roots of $f(x)$ (they are square roots of the roots of $y^2+10y+1$) and check whether any of them has degree 2 over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Here, the degree of my polynomial is 4 and it has no real root. But what about reducibility @Dane?

Answer (score 1):

Hey whenever the expression contains even powers of $x$ you can always take $x^2=t$, to reduce the equation to :
**$$t^2+10t+1$$** which is a quadratic polynomial over $t$

Now follow the usual factorization as you would for the quadratic expression....

**$$t^2+10t+1=(t- \alpha)(t- \beta)$$** where
$$\alpha =\frac{-10+\sqrt{96}}{2}$$

$$\beta=\frac{-10-\sqrt{96}}{2}$$
Now put back $t=x^2$ and now you will see that the factors will lead to two more factors

**$$(x^2-\alpha)(x^2-\beta)$$**
which will give you 4 factors:
**$$(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)(x-\beta)(x+\beta)$$**

Hope this helps …...