# Doubt in'Finding irreducible polynomial'

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is from Artin Algebra Sec 15.4:

[image]
[image]

> I can't understand how did we conclude that $x^4-10x^2+1$ is irredducible over $\Bbb Q$ from the discussion of para above example 15.4.4.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204279/show-that-x4-10x21-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665435/x4-10x2-1-is-irreducible-over-mathbb-q?noredirect=1&lq=1). The answers there prove the claim of Example $15.4.4$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\gamma$ is a zero of $x^4-10x^2+1$ over the rationals and this is the lowest degree polynomial with this property. So it must be irreducible.