# $P(x)=-x^5+10x^3-20x+12$ is irreducible

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I would like to prove that $P(x)=-x^5+10x^3-20x+12$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$

I tried using Eisenstein's criterion, reduction and factorizing but I didn't succeed, any idea ?

Comment: What reductions have you tried?

Comment: @MarkBennet I tried modulo $2$ but I get $-x^5$ and modulo $3$ but I failed seeing why $-X^5+X^3-2X$ is irreducible, perhaps I am misleading somewhere.

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility of a linear factor?

Comment: @MarkBennet I try it again.

Comment: @JeSuis $-X^5+X^3-2X$ is not irreducible in $\Bbb F_3[X]$ : it's clearly a multiple of $X$. If you want to prove irreducibility of a monic polynomial by reducing $\pmod p$, you have to pick a $p$ that does not divide the constant term.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  arf right... Thansk for the advise!

Comment: Further hint: $x^5+x^3-2x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks, can you please look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956386/explicit-expression-minimal-polynomial-which-is-equal-to-characteristic ? If you want only, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rational root theorem, $f(x)$ has no rational roots. For $f(p/q)=0$ would imply $p\mid 12$ and $q\mid 1$, and no such value works. By the Gauss Lemma it is enough to show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. Then 
$$
f(x)=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(-x^2+dx+e)
$$ 
leads to a contradiction over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Eisenstein's criterion does apply to $f(-x+2)=x^5-10x^4+30x^3-20x^2-20x+20$ with respect to $p=5$.