# Eisenstein Criterion to verify a that a polynomial is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $f(x)= x^4 -10x^2+1.$

Using the rational root theorem, I see that the polynomial has no rational root. Therefore, it does not have any linear factor. If it's reducible over $\mathbb{Z},$ then it would a product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials.

I did this pathetic arithmetic, and then I have shown that the polynomial is in fact, irreducible over $\mathbb{Z},$ ie irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ by the Gauss's lemma.

Is there any better way to check that the polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? Can we use Eisenstein Criterion by translating the polynomial? Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks so much.

Comment: This question already has many answers. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204279/show-that-x4-10x21-is-irreducible-over-mathbbq?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will close my post now.