# Factorizing polynomials over finite fields and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

I have the following problem:

> Factor the integer polynomial $x^5+2x^4+3x^3+5$ modulo 2, and over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For $2$, the polynomial becomes $f(x)=x^5+x^3+1$. It is easy to check if it has roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, namely $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1$, so, it doesn't have roots. Wouldn't this mean the polynomial is irreducible? Or is there something I am missing?

As for $\mathbb{Q}$, I'd think I can also try to find the roots, but it's a polynomial of degree five, so finding the roots is not trivial. So, there probably is a different method. I'd appreciate any help because I really don't know.

Comment: You still need to exclude the possibility of factoring $f(x)$ as a product of a degree $2$ and a degree $3$ polynomial. The rational roots you can exclude using [the rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Comment: Just to follow up, the irreducible polynomials of degree 2 and 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ are $x^2+x+1$, and $x^3+x^2+1$, $x^3+x+1$, respectively. I can simply try both combinations and find that they are not factor of $x^5+x^3+1$. So, would that be enough to show that that polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Correct, @Schach21. Actually checking divisibility by that quadratic factor is enough. For if a degree $n$ polynomial factors then one factor has degree at most $n/2$. Just like when you test an integer $q$ for primality you only ever need to est potential factors up to $\sqrt{q}$. With polynomials we use the degree as a substitute for *size*. Only this time the size of the product is the SUM of the sizes of the factors (rather than their product). Here $n/2=5/2$ so one factor would have to be at most quadratic.

Comment: Irreducibility over $\Bbb{Q}$ follows from irreducibility over $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and Gauss's lemma. I try to explain it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2872728/11619). The theme has been touched by many other users (in other threads) also.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So, the polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but it's reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, so wouldn't that contradict what you said in your answer (and also here), namely that the polynomial in question is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: No. The flow of logic is a one-way street. If a monic polynomial with integer coefficients is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$, then it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. But the other direction fails. Such a polynomial can even be reducible over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for ALL PRIMES $p$, and still be irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160858/11619).

Comment: Similarly, if such a polynomial is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$, by Gauss's lemma it is reducible over $\Bbb{Z}$. Hence automatically reducible over $\Bbb{Z}_p$ for all primes $p$. The difficult (sometimes impossible) direction is to "lift" a factorization modulo $p$ to a factorization over $\Bbb{Z}$.