# why is $x^6-x^5 + x^3 - x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

> Why is $x^6-x^5 + x^3 - x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

It clearly has no integer roots, and in fact no real roots. Every polynomial with real coefficients can be written as a product of quadratic and linear terms. But I'm not sure how to factor the above polynomial. Maybe some sort of theorem involving irreducible integer polynomials might be useful?

Comment: With respect to which set are you interested in factoring the polynomial?

Comment: With respect to $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. Was that not clear in the problem statement?

Comment: Observe that the equation $x^6 + x^3 + 1 = x^5 + x^2$ has **no** _integer solutions_ due to **opposite** parity, (comparing LHS with RHS)

Comment: I did not find your goal clear since you cited the theorem that every polynomial with real coefficients can be expressed as a product of linear factors and irreducible quadratic factors with respect to the real numbers.

Comment: It is irreducible modulo $2$, because in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ it isn't divisible by any of the irreducible polynomials of degree $\le 3$: $x$, $x+1$, $x^2+x+1$, $x^3+x+1$, $x^3+x^2+1$ (a quick paper & pencil check gives this, ask if you need help). The claim follows from this because reduction modulo a prime is a homomorphism of rings.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen why is your last statement sufficient to solve the problem? Also, for finding irreducible polynomials, isn’t there a sieve of Eratosthenes method similar to the analogous one for prime number checking?

Comment: Sufficiency is explained for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2872306/11619). Yes, we can run an analogue of sieve of Eratosthenes to find irreducible monic polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}_p[x]$. But I think there are even more efficient methods to do the same. Of course, in this small case any method will do. The catch is that there are polynomials irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ but reducible modulo **every** prime $p$. So this is not a universal tool, just one of many.

Comment: @user33096 _For this problem_ Jyrki doesn't need a general method for finding irreducible polynomials over $\Bbb Z_2$,  He just needs to know what they are up through degree 3. There are only 4 of these, and he already had them memorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^{6} - x^{5} + x^{3} - x^{2} + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Consider the polynomial $g(x) = f(x+2) = 37 + 120x + 165x^2 + 121x^3 + 50x^4 + 11x^5 +x^6$. We note that the coefficients are all positive and bounded by $165$. We have that $g(172) = 27592587407701$ and $g(172)$ is prime. By [Cohn's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohn%27s_irreducibility_criterion) , $g(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, and it follows $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. A bit overkill, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I'm wasn't sure whether to upvote this or laugh, so I did both.

Comment: Also with $h(x)=f(x+1)=x^6+5x^5+10x^4+11x^3+7x^2+2x+1$ and $h(15)=15732481$ prime.

Answer (score 4):

We have a monic degree-$6$ polynomial with no real roots and constant term $1$, so if it is reducible it has a monic quadratic factor with constant term dividing $1$. There are only three such quadratic polynomials with nonreal roots: $x^2-x+1$, $x^2 + 1$, and $x^2+x+1$. None of these divide your polynomial, so it is irreducible.

---

Another method: Any monic factor $g(x)$ satisfies $g(x) > 0$ for all real $x$. Combined with the fact that $f(-1) = f(0) = f(1) = 1$, we have $g(-1) = g(0) = g(1) = 1$. Thus if $g(x)$ has degree $\le 2$, $g(x)$ must be a constant. So $f(x)$ has no degree-$2$ factors and is therefore irreducible.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I have ever seen the combination of lack of real roots and constant term $+1$ used in this way :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar proof as one in @conan's answer, with a smaller prime. We use [Murty's irreducibility criterion](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/2docuat2011/teoria_de_numeros/Irreducible.pdf):

> Let $f(x)=a_mx^m+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and set $$H=\max_{0\leq i\leq m-1} |a_i/a_m|.$$
> If $f(n)$ is prime for some integer $n\geq H+2$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

We can use this directly on our polynomial $f(x)=x^6-x^5 + x^3 - x^2 + 1$ where $H=1$ and for $n=4$ we get $f(n)=3121$ a prime.

(Note that using it on the reciprocal $\overline{f}(x)=x^6-x^4+x^3-x+1$ for $n=3$ gives slightly smaller prime $\overline{f}(n)=673$).